Book/series in which the protagonists were a family of red-haired people, I believe royals, in a war or conflict
I had read a book series years back and would like to find it again. It was fantasy set in its own world, but aside from the below scenes, I don't recall much more for specifics. This would have been somewhere between 2009 to 2014, most likely young adult fiction.
The protagonists were a family of red-haired people, I believe royals, and they were in a war or conflict. It starts with a woman who is young and leading an army, and the cover featured her with her long red hair shining like fire, as was also a scene in the book.
Some scenes included an older man fighting alongside an older woman who chewed a root to stain her teeth red; this may have been a prologue at the beginning of the book. Another book is about the son of the red-haired woman, and in it he was in a foreign land and upon meeting an old woman, who noted that he was just a boy and he broke down crying with his friend/travel companion of a similar young age and her comforting them.
If anyone has any leads, it would be greatly appreciated!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What were some of the fantastic elements?  Was there magic?  Magical people?  Fantastic creatures?

I tried searching for your story. I found that chewing betel nut gives people red teeth.

Marion Zimmer Bradley's Darkover books feature an elite caste with mostly red hair and often psychic powers. But I don't recall the second scene. The first sounds like the cover of "Stormqueen".

Jirel of Joiry? The cover matches but I have the book and there is no older woman with stained teeth.

Definitely not Stormqueen, but I think I will check out the book. (Hit post too soon.) The covered had the woman protagonist on armor with her helm off, back to the sun illuminating long red flowing off to the side in the wind. She stood on brown rocky ground, possibly a cliff, with landscape that was either hilled or mountanous in the background.
